# Update set From Select Error Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax, nested

Im trying to use Update set like above, i try different kind of syntaxes but no success

```
update 
pc_discount
set 
ceza_ucret_turu_id=pc_discount_ceza.CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU 
from 
(select CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU from pc_discount_ceza where CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU is not null) pdc
where 
pc_discount.id=pdc.discount_id
ceza_ucret_turu_id is null
```

first one no success(sql command not finished properly)

```
MERGE INTO pc_discount pd
  USING pc_discount_ceza pdc
  ON pd.id = pdc.discount_id
     AND pdc.CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU is not null
     and pd.ceza_ucret_turu_id is null
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE 
  SET ceza_ucret_turu_id = pdc.CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU
```

no success again(missing ON keyword)

Is there any advice to run that kind of sql?

EDIT:

```
update 
pc_discount
set 
ceza_ucret_turu_id=pdc.CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU 
from 
(select CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU from pc_discount_ceza where CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU is not null) pdc
where 
pc_discount.id=pdc.discount_id and
ceza_ucret_turu_id is null
```

still no change.

Comment: does the subquery return any results `select CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU from pc_discount_ceza where CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU is not null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would change

- there are two conditions, they need joining with an "AND" set should
- use the table alias in the set
- add the joining condition into the subquery

Try something like

```
update 
  pc_discount
set 
  ceza_ucret_turu_id = pcd.CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU 
from 
  ( 
     select 
       discount_id, 
       CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU 
     from 
       pc_discount_ceza 
     where
       CEZA_ALT_UCRET_KODU is not null
  ) pcd 
where 
  pc_discount.id = pcd.discount_id and 
  pc_discount.ceza_ucret_turu_id is null
```

Comment: Its underlining first 'FROM' keyword

Comment: just noticed the joining field in the subquery was also missing

Comment: In addition im using pl/sql with toad? It it causes any differences?

Comment: Cannot answer that - not familiar with toad.  I doubt that the sql would be different though

Comment: There could be one to many relation with pd.id=pdc.discount_id

Comment: so when there is more than one value returned from pdc, which value do you want to take?  What are your business rules?

Comment: actually they are exacly same,taking one of them is okey.

Comment: please see my amended answer below

Answer (score -1):

Try this - I'm not sure you're using correct syntax for Oracle

```
UPDATE pc_discount    pd
SET ceza_ucret_turu_id =
 (SELECT
   MAX(ceza_alt_ucret_kodu)
  FROM 
   pc_discount_ceza  pdc
  WHERE pd.id = pdc.discount_id
 )
WHERE pd.ceza_ucret_turu_id IS NULL
;
```

The above has been updated with your new business rule

Comment: [Error] Execution (62: 3): ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Thanks for marking that down - but the subquery comes from you - I cannot see your data so I cannot know your primary keys.  Rather than marking my answer down how about you supply more information so I can help.  My first line still stands - you're using the wrong syntax